# Sending value from FormView form_valid() to success_url without using url

Tags: django, django-forms, django-class-based-views

How to send this value to success_url?

```
class AnyView(FormView):
    ...
    success_url = reverse_lazy('success')
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        ...
        value = 'blablabla' # <<< How to pass this value?
        messages.success(self.request, f'Sua matrícula foi realizada.')
        return super(AnyView, self).form_valid(form)
```

**success.html**

```
{{ value }}
```

**I don't want to send it by url**

```
path('anyform', AnyView.as_view(), name='anyform'),
```

Comment: you can add the variable to the view context, like in this example https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial03/#a-shortcut-render

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@alv2017's comment helped me.

```
class AnyView(FormView):
...

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(AnyView, self).get_context_data()
    return context

def form_valid(self, form):
    ...
    context['value'] = 'blablabla'
    messages.success(self.request, f'Sua matrícula foi realizada.')
    return render(self.request, 'success.html', context)
```